# How to have conditional source-maps in next.js

Tags: webpack, next.js, source-maps

I have a next project where sometimes we would like to debug certain ui elements on the fly. The source map currently on production is minified but I have seen at some places that there are ways where if you send a query param like ?isDev=true then all of a sudden you have source maps which are not minified and helps debug easily. Does anyone have any idea how I can achieve this?

Have thought about configuring this somehow from AWS end.